# Having issues with my StackExchange login

Tags: support, chat, user-accounts, login

I didn't think my [StackExchange user](http://stackexchange.com/users/1486612/charles-koppelman) (the one I use for chat) had a different login than my mi.yodeya user.  It's always been pretty seamless navigating between the two.  Well, I just reinstalled my browser and now I'm having issues logging in for chat (not for the main site).

Any help?

Comment: Your [chat user](http://chat.stackexchange.com/users/39351/charles-koppelman) currently shows Mi Yodeya as your parent site.  Was it previously some other site?  (I don't know why that would matter, but chat sometimes randomly re-parents accounts, so just asking.)  Does it happen in other browsers too?

Comment: @MonicaCellio no, that makes sense.  And I haven't tried another browser today.

Comment: What browser are you using?

Comment: @MonicaCellio Firefox.  But I manually copied my settings from my old computer.  I can delete all my cookies and try again

Comment: Did you try http://stackexchange.com/users/chat-login and, failing that, http://chat.stackexchange.com/help?

Comment: @msh210 the problem with /users/chat-login is that (and this should be in the post) it tells me re the openid user, `This login is new to Stack Exchange`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Deleting my cookies from stackexchange.com and then logging on to chat from english.SE seemed to work.  I can now use judaism.SE's chat, too.

Comment: Note - you can always [contact the Stack Exchange team](http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/contact/other) if you're unable to log in and can't seem to fix it. We generally get these types of issues resolved quickly.